# How many options are there for selecting a scoop of ice cream with up to $3$ toppings?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have $8$ flavors of ice cream and $10$ types of topping.

How many options do you have if you can only take one scoop but up to $3$ toppings?

Toppings can't be repeated and the order does not matter.

Is $$8 \times 10 + 8 \times 10 \times 9 + 8 \times 10 \times 9 \times 8 + 8$$ right? I mean so you can choose what ever you like or?

Thanks a lot.

Peter

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit your question to show what you tried and where you are stuck. Can you work out a smaller problem, with two flavors and two toppings?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Can toppings be repeated? Does the order in which the toppings are placed matter?

Comment: Toppings can't be repeated and the order does not matter. Is 

8 x 10 + 
8 x 10 x 9 + 
8 x 10 x 9 x 8 + 
8 
right? I mean so you can choose what ever you like or?

Comment: Perter, your answer is for toppings can't be repeated and order does matter.  If order doesn't matter, it would be 8*(C(10,0)+C(10,1)+...+C(10,3)).

Answer (score 2):

Break the problem into 2 steps.  Pick the ice cream then decide on the toppings.
The number of ways to do this is the number of ways to pick the ice cream times the number of ways to select the toppings.
The number of ways to selecting the toppings should be partitioned into selecting 0,1,2, or 3.  Find number of ways of selecting i toppings. If order doesn't matter but you can repeat, to find this count, you use a method often known as "balls in boxes" or "donut" problem solutions. You can find discussion of this type of problem in Rosen's **Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications** in the chapters on counting.  The number of ways to select i toppings from 10 is C(9+i,i) where i=0,..,10.

If on the other hand order is not important but you cannot repeat toppings, then the answer would be  8* (C(10,0)+C(10,1)+C(10,2)+C(10,3)).  If order is important and you cannot repeat it is 8*(1+10+10*9+10*9*8) ways, which is the way you were approaching it, Peter. So your answer depends whether order is important and whether toppings can be repeated.

Comment: You should update your answer to reflect the added information that toppings cannot be repeated and the order in which they are applied does not matter.

Comment: I did actually, in comments above (under Peter's update of criterion.).  In this case it is 8*(C(10,0)+C(10,1)+C(10,2)+C(10,3)).

Comment: You should place that information in your answer so that the question can be closed with a correct answer.

Comment: I added information that you suggested.

Comment: Your answer for the intended question, order is not important and toppings cannot be repeated, is correct, as is your answer for the case in which order is not important and toppings may be repeated.  However, your answer for the case if order is important and toppings cannot be repeated is incorrect.

Comment: If order is important and toppings cannot be repeated, then there are $8$ orders without toppings, $8 \cdot 10$ with one topping, $8 \cdot 10 \cdot 9$ with two toppings, and $8 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8$ with three toppings, for a total of $8(1 + 10 + 10 \cdot 9 + 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8)$.